# Postman 304 Not Modified error, spring rest api

Tags: spring, api, postman

[Postman image body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIq2y.png)

[Postman image header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZvRk.png)

I trying to send POST method to Spring rest api but it always shows me a 304 error. Did anyone know what could cause this problem?
Thanks

Client Controller.java(spring controller)

```
   /* change client ip and client port. if change successful, save the settings to the dabase */
        @RequestMapping(value = "/clients/setConfiguration/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<?> setConfiguration(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody ClientConfigDTO clientConfigDTO) {

            System.out.println("POST: ClientController.setConfiguration for client " + id);

            HttpStatus result = clientService.setConfiguration(id, clientConfigDTO);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(result);

        }
```

ClientConfigDto.java

```
 package at.fhwn.ma.serverapp.dto;

    public class ClientConfigDTO {

        private String ip;
        private String port;

        public ClientConfigDTO() {}

        public ClientConfigDTO(String ip, String port) {
            this.ip=ip;
            this.port=port;
        }

        public String getIp() {
            return ip;
        }
        public void setIp(String ip) {
            this.ip = ip;
        }
        public String getPort() {
            return port;
        }
        public void setPort(String port) {
            this.port = port;
        }

    }
```

Comment: First, 304 is not an error. It probably simply means that clientService.setConfiguration() returns HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED.

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks for correction.Well, I want to change the value in the database with this, but after the request the value remains the same ......

Comment: *the value in the database with this, but after the request the value remains the same*: I have no idea of what you're talking about: what is "the value in the database" and "this"? Anyway, have you checked what clientService.setConfiguration() returns?